Is the implicit function unique?

Does the equation $$xy^2+xz^3+\ln z=0$$ define the unique implicit function
$z=g(x,y)$ in the neighborhood of $(0,1)$? If yes, compute
$\dfrac{dz}{dx}(0,1)$ and $\dfrac{dz}{dy}(0,1).$

My attempt:
Let $f(x,y,z)=xy^2+xz^3+\ln z$. Notice that $f(0,1,z)=0\iff z=1$. So, $f(0,1,1)=0$. On the other hand, we have $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,1,1)=1\neq 0$. Then the Implicit function theorem tells that there exists a solution $z=g(x,y)$ around $(0,1)$ s.t $f(x,y,g(x,y))=0$.
But I'm stuck at the "unique" part since the Implicit function theorem only mentions $z=g(x,y)$ is unique if we limit $z$ is continuous. In this case, $z$ may be not continuous.
Could anyone help me to finish the rest of the problem? Thanks in advance!

Does unique function mean it's bijective?

no, of course not

Can you please define what's a unique function?

It's just there is only one function satisfies the given equation.

@leemax You can see https://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20199/notes/Chapter3/S3.1.html, in particular, Some special cases of the implicit function theorem, $n=2, k=1$.

@RiverLi not so helpful. I need to covey its uniqueness

I think the statement of the theorem in Wiki is not good (I already modified it) but I think the reference @RiverLi posted answers the question you asked. Under the conditions stated for the implicit function theorem there exists exactly one function. So there does not exist another one. And this one that exists has the proepry that it is contiously differentiable. So what is unclear now?
